# iPhone 10 and 11 doesn't have enough height after running the app on xcode 11

Tags: ios, ios13, xcode11

So i have an app built in xcode 10.2.1 then I later run the app on Xcode 11. The app show black screen since the view doesnt have enough height(only 48.0, why???). All devices are working fine but iPhone 10 and 11 running on iOS 13 does have a bug.

Note: No storyboard used, the app was built in Xcode 10.2.1, swift 5, iOS 13 iPhone 5 - 8 are working fine

Here is the Hierarchy of the view: https://www.dropbox.com/s/e3mzzpwn8iozhc0/Screen%20Shot%202019-10-08%20at%2012.11.18%20PM.png?dl=0

I tried using SceneDelegate but didnt worked. I also tried to opted out using scenes.

AppDelegate.swift

```
var window: UIWindow?
private var appCoordinator: AppCoordinator!

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        FirebaseApp.configure()

        window = UIWindow()
        appCoordinator = AppCoordinator(window: window!)
        appCoordinator.start{}

        return true
}
```

AppCoordinator.swift

```
class AppCoordinator: BaseCoordinator {
    private let window: UIWindow
    private let dependencies: AppDependency

    init(window: UIWindow) {
        self.window = window
        self.dependencies = AppDependency()
    }

    override func start(completion: @escaping CoordinatorCompletion) {
        showTabBarController()
    }

    /// Always represent tabbar controller when authentication state changed
    func showTabBarController() {
        let tabCoordinator = TabCoordinator(window: window, dependencies: dependencies)
        coordinate(to: tabCoordinator)
    }

}
```

TabCoordinator.swift

```
class TabCoordinator: BaseCoordinator {
    typealias Dependencies = HasAPIClient & HasUserManager & HasLanguageManager & HasSpotSocketEngine & HasFuturesSocketEngine
    private let window: UIWindow
    private let dependencies: Dependencies

    enum SectionTab: Int, Menu {
        //case home
        case futures
        case trading
        case wallet
        case account

        func title(languageManager: LanguageManager) -> String {
            switch self {
            //case .home: return languageManager.localizedString("router.home")
            case .futures: return languageManager.localizedString("router.futures")
            case .trading: return languageManager.localizedString("router.spot")
            case .wallet: return languageManager.localizedString("router.wallets")
            case .account: return languageManager.localizedString("router.account")
            }
        }

        var image: UIImage {
            switch self {
            //case .home: return UIImage.init(named: "icTabHome")!
            case .futures: return UIImage.init(named: "icTabFutures")!
            case .trading: return UIImage.init(named: "icTabTrading")!
            case .wallet: return UIImage.init(named: "icTabWallet")!
            case .account: return UIImage.init(named: "icTabAccount")!
            }
        }

        var highlightedImage: UIImage {
            switch self {
            //case .home: return UIImage.init(named: "icTabHomeActive")!
            case .futures: return UIImage.init(named: "icTabFutures")!
            case .trading: return UIImage.init(named: "icTabTradingActive")!
            case .wallet: return UIImage.init(named: "icTabWalletActive")!
            case .account: return UIImage.init(named: "icTabAccountActive")!
            }
        }

    }

    init(window: UIWindow, dependencies: Dependencies) {
        self.window = window
        self.dependencies = dependencies
    }

    override func start(completion: @escaping CoordinatorCompletion) {
        super.start(completion: completion)

        let tabbarController = UITabBarController()
        let tabs : [SectionTab] = [.futures, .trading, .wallet, .account]
        let viewControllers = createViewControllers(tabs: tabs)

        tabbarController.viewControllers = viewControllers.map{ $0.viewController }
        tabbarController.view.backgroundColor = .white
        tabbarController.tabBar.tintColor = UIColor.appLightBlue
        tabbarController.tabBar.unselectedItemTintColor = UIColor.appDarkGray

        let notification = Notification.Name.init(LanguageChangedNotification)
        NotificationCenter.default.rx.notification(notification).subscribe({_ in
            tabbarController.viewControllers?.enumerated().forEach({ (arg0) in
                let (offset, vc) = arg0
                vc.tabBarItem.title = tabs[offset].title(languageManager: self.dependencies.languageManager)
            })
        }).disposed(by: disposeBag)

        window.rootViewController = tabbarController
        window.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }

    private func createViewControllers(tabs: [SectionTab]) -> [(viewController: UIViewController, coordinator: BaseCoordinator)] {
        return tabs.map({ (tab) -> (viewController: UIViewController, coordinator: BaseCoordinator) in
            let viewController: UIViewController

            let coordinator: BaseCoordinator
            switch tab {
            case .futures:
                viewController = BTSENavigationController()
                coordinator = FuturesCoordinator(navigationController: viewController as! BTSENavigationController, dependencies: dependencies)
                coordinate(to: coordinator)
            case .trading:
                viewController = BTSENavigationController()
                coordinator = SpotCoordinator(navigationController: viewController as! BTSENavigationController, dependencies: dependencies)
                coordinate(to: coordinator)
            case .wallet:
                viewController = BTSENavigationController()
                coordinator = WalletCoordinator(navigationController: viewController as! BTSENavigationController, dependencies: dependencies, url: self.dependencies.client.url(for: .wallets))
                coordinate(to: coordinator)
            case .account:
                viewController = BTSENavigationController()
                coordinator = AccountCoordinator(navigationController: viewController as! BTSENavigationController, dependencies: dependencies)
                coordinate(to: coordinator)
            }

            viewController.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem.init(title: tab.title(languageManager: dependencies.languageManager), image: tab.image, selectedImage: tab.highlightedImage)

            return (viewController: viewController, coordinator: coordinator)
        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is this. To those who are stuck with this problem like me.

https://github.com/tonySwiftDev/UITabbar-fixIOS12.1Bug/issues/4

Thanks!